# DMS is failing to connect to already working endpoint: Failed in prepare imp for Redshift Base general error

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I am using DMS to migrate date from MySQL to Redshift. I need to add new task,but it does not run because endpoint connection test fails, but I use already working endpoint. Although task with this endpoint is running without error, test is failing with this strange error

`Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed in prepare imp for Redshift Base general error.`

Answer (score 0):

Restarting DMS instance fixed the issue.